# Postgresql: DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I want to delete a constraint only if it exists. But it's not working or I do something wrong.

Here is my query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints WHERE constraint_name='res_partner_bank_unique_number')
THEN ALTER TABLE res_partner_bank DROP CONSTRAINT res_partner_bank_unique_number;
```

It gives me this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"

If anybody can help me please.
Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `IF`in SQL (only in PL/pgSQL).

But [drop constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) supports the `IF NOT EXISTS` option:

```
ALTER TABLE res_partner_bank 
  DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS res_partner_bank_unique_number;
```